# What is the appropriate entity type for working with entities in a disconnected scenario?

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4.1

In my application I need to retrieve partial graph of entities.
These entities are processed by the user and later should be saved.
thus the returning and saving contexts differ but I need changes tracking for the whole graph.
As far as I know STEs are deprecated now
But I do not know what type of entities to choose for this scenario.
Can anyone give the explanation?

Answer (score 1):

You may try below one.

**Inserting a disconnected entity**

Here’s the generic version of `Insert<>` which can insert any disconnected entity.

```
public TEntity Insert<TEntity>(TEntity entity) 
            where TEntity : EntityObject 
{ 
    AddTo<TEntity>(entity); 
    this.SaveChanges(true); 
    // Without this, attaching new entity of same type in same context fails. 
    this.Detach(entity); 
    return entity; 
}
```

**Inserting disconnected child entities**

The common principle of inserting a child entity is :

1. first you have to attach the parent entity in the context,
2. then you will have to set the mapping between the parent and the child (you can’t have the mapping already!),
3. and then you will have to call SaveChanges.

Here’s the code:

```
public TEntity Insert<TParent, TEntity>(
    TParent parent,
    Action<TParent, TEntity> addChildToParent,
    TEntity entity)
    where TEntity : EntityObject
    where TParent : EntityObject
{
    AddTo<TParent, TEntity>(parent, addChildToParent, entity);
    this.SaveChanges();
    this.AcceptAllChanges();
    // Without this, consequtive insert using same parent in same context fails.
    this.Detach(parent); 
    // Without this, attaching new entity of same type in same context fails.
    this.Detach(entity);
    return entity;
}

private void AddTo<TParent, TEntity>(TParent parent, 
    Action<TParent, TEntity> addChildToParent, 
    TEntity entity) 
    where TEntity : EntityObject
    where TParent : EntityObject
{
    Attach<TParent>(parent);            
    addChildToParent(parent, entity);            
}
```

You can get more details from [**Entity Framework working in fully disconnected Here**](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/81543/Finally-Entity-Framework-working-in-fully-disconne)

I hope this will help to you.